# Why does sed replace all occurrences instead of only the first occurrence?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace the first occurrence in a file using `sed`:

```
sed -i s/he/He/ dummy.txt
```

Instead of replacing first occurrence, it replaces all the occurrences, even without `/g`.

According to the documentation it should replace the first only.

The `sed` version which is:

```
GNU sed version 4.1.5
```

Am I missing anything? Or does the behavior differ for different `sed` implementations?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah. I have seen that link. But most of the tutorials or other sites mentioned that without /g sed will replace the first occurence only. So I'm getting different result due to version or something?

Comment: `sed` is basically a line editor - it works on one line at a time (unless you program it to read more lines into its buffer (called the *pattern space*).  Where you have seen "*`g` will replace the first occurrence only*" refers to the first occurrence in the current *pattern space*, ie. in the current line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed processes input line by line. The `/g` modifier influences whether it replaces all the occurrences on a line, or only the first one:

```
echo hehe | sed s/h/H/
echo hehe | sed s/h/H/g
```

To replace only the first occurrence in the file, use something like the following:

```
s/h/H/            # Replace.
ta                # Go to a if s/// worked.
b                 # Otherwise, start the next cycle.
:a { n            # Process the next line.
     ba           # Go to a.
}
```

Comment: That `g` thing is a real red herring. You'd think there would be some other option by now to differentiate line level "global" from the (non-existent) file level "global".